# SiC MOSFET Gate resistor sizing

Tags: mosfet-driver, gate-driving

We have designed a gate driver circuit using the UCC21710 gate driver for our Motor controller, We have chosen a starting value of 2 ohms(OUTH and OUTL or Ron and Roff).
Here is the circuit

[image: Gate Driver Circuit]

According to the gate resistor calculations provided in the datasheet, the SiC mosfet would need about 4.6 Amps, so by using a 2 ohms resistor, the sink and source currents of the gate driver would be about 5.3 A and 5.8 A respectively.
[image: Gate Current calculation]

Now when we actually run the motor(With Ron=2 ohm and Roff=2 ohm, Lets call this **CASE 1**), we observe a lot of instability(Most probably due to the fast switching of the SiC MOSFET and due to high dv/dt coupling), We measured the Motor phase to phase voltage.The raise time and fall time of the PWM pulses were about 16ns and 26ns.

**CASE 2**:We then modified the Ron resistor to 10 ohms(Roff was not changed, it is still 2 ohm). We saw there was a reduction in the instability drastically. But still if we increased the load on the motor (> 5Nm), the instability would again start coming. Our requirement is to run the motor with a load of 10Nm.
The raise time and fall time of the PWM pulses were about 40ns and 110ns respectively.

**CASE 3**:Next we tried modifying Ron to 18 ohm and Roff to 4.7 ohm, In this case we observed instability the moment the motor started running.(similar to CASE 1)

Is there any rule of thumb that we can follow in sizing these resistors?
I read in a few application notes that we need to measure the gate voltage and see the amount of ringing happening and then size the gate resistors appropriately(Q factor also comes into effect here, critically damped or underdamped gate..etc),
Link https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla385a/slla385a.pdf?ts=1693240200994&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F
But in our case probing the gate, especially on the high voltage side is quiet difficult and risky and would rather avoid it as much as possible..

Comment: Please show your layout, and if possible oscilloscope waveforms + how you probe. IMO layout is more important than specific values of these components.

Comment: @tobalt Only the Motor terminals have been probed(motor is about 1 meter away from the PCB), To see the change in the raise and fall times of the PWM pulses. I understand the layout is important, but at the moment the layout is fixed and cannot changed. If you could be more specific on which part of the layout you need I can add those images. I was hoping to get a gate resistor based solution, because we have had some success by changing the gate resistors(CASE 2), I know this is going to be a trial and error process, but with some guidance, I was hoping to minimize the number of trials.

Comment: The important part is the layout of the stuff in your schematic snippet + possibly the placement of the input capacitance (of the half bridge voltage). And if you are trying to debug the driver I suggest you also probe at the driver and not at the far end of a connected cable.